# Why use http requests in rest APIs to communicate data?

Tags: rest, http, frontend, backend

Why use http request in rest APIs to communicate data between services? Are there any alternative methods? Why http requests are best way for it? What are the benefits of using https. Can we use ftp as well for rest APIs.

I need to find the reasons and other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP protocol being very widespread, it makes it quite easy to interface clients/servers together.
The advantage of developing a REST API is to have plenty of tools available to facilitate the development and security of the API.
However, in terms of optimizing the size of the data transferred, HTTP is far from being an optimized protocol.
In addition to REST APIs, there are also JSON-RPC APIs. which are also based on HTTP. There are also APIs based on protocols other than HTTP.